# vba scrape html - get element with dynamic class

Tags: vba, web-scraping

using excel vba i need to scrape the date (2019-01-16).
this code works great:

```
Set wyjatek = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("redesignTravelHistory tank-thlist__date 2019-01-16")(0)
```

but the problem is, that in every html I try to scrape, this date can be different.
Do you know how to solve it?

part of html:

```
<div class="redesignTravelHistory tank-thlist__date 2019-01-16">16/01/2019</div>
```

Comment: 1. use `getElementsByTagName("div")` to get a collection of all divs. 2. Loop throught that collection and use `className` property to read the class name. 3. Use string functions or `LIKE` to match a pattern in the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the first element that contains 3 classes

- redesignTravelHistory
- tank-thlist__date
- 2019-01-16

I'm guessing that the date class "2019-01-16" is irrelevant and can be removed.

> ```
>  Set wyjatek = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("redesignTravelHistory tank-thlist__date")(0)
> ```

Comment: Heck...I didn't realize that you could query multiple class name till I read your post.  Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a css attribute = value selector with ^ operator (value starts with substring after the =)

```
ie.document.querySelector("div[class^='redesignTravelHistory tank-thlist__date']")
```

If there can be more than one element matched with this then use querySelectorAll and index in to the nodeList to get the right element e.g. index 1

```
ie.document.querySelectorAll("div[class^='redesignTravelHistory tank-thlist__date']").item(1)
```